# How to configure ProGuard to respect Jackson model?

Tags: java, android, gradle, jackson, proguard

The following class describes a model I read from a .json file using [Jackson 2.2](http://jackson.codehaus.org).

```
public class Product {
    public String name;
    public int width;
}
```

The [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org) build process invokes [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net) to shrink and obfuscate the release build.
When I start the application the following error message occurs:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: 
  Unrecognized field "name" (class com.example.b.c), 
  not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
```

How can I configure ProGuard or annotate the `Product` class so that Jackson still works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have to admin that I simplified the example in my question. The solution to the problem was to keep **getters** and **setters** in ProGuard which I had to additionally define in model classes to make Jackson work.

```
-keep public class com.example.models.Product {
  public *** get*();
  public void set*(***);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, seeing this makes so much sense, but it wasn't obvious to me even so many years later.

Answer (score 2):

To build on [JJD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50268555/6452943)'s answer, what helped my use case is:

```
#json contaning unobfuscated names can be read and set by Jackson
-keep public class com.xyz.yourmodel,com.xyz.c.yourmodel2,com.xyz.models.** {
    private <fields>;
    public void set*(***);
    public *** get*();
}

#to preserve Jackson annotations like @JsonIgnore
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.* *;
}

#dont throw warnings from here
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
```

I used jackson in Android app to convert objects to json and json to objects. The app also receives json from a web app which has full field names. Since proguard in android obfuscates all names, I was getting an error only while processing json from web.
So for the json containing unobfuscated names, getters and setters of model classes are kept.

Since getters are setters are kept, while converting object to json, jackson was adding both obfuscated and unobfuscated names to json (data duplication) . To prevent that, private fields of model classes are kept. So now only full unobfuscated fields are present in json.

Referred [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonOnAndroid) page for annotations rule

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@jsonProperty** annotation

Answer (score 0):

In many cases these classes already implement the Serializable interface. It could make sense to keep all those classes implementing this interface depending on your project. If so add this line to you proguard configuration.

```
-keep class * implements java.io.Serializable
```